# How to achieve a secure system BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, security, broadcastreceiver

I have this broadcast receiver in my app and got an "Insecure Broadcast Receivers registered dynamically" vulnerability when analyzing the APK in AppKnox.

Since this is a broadcast sent by the system, I'm having trouble finding how to make it secure. Do system broadcasts come with permission already?

[image]

How could I go about securing this?

Comment: That is a false positive, its a system broadcast you cant secure it

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!